# How many ways to distribute six different books among $13$ children if no child gets more than one book

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to distribute six different books among $13$ children if no child gets more than one book?

So I think the issue right now is I may have thought too deeply about the question.

Initially I thought the solution was $\binom{13}{6}$, but then I began to wonder what exactly the question is asking.  Are there $6$ different types of books and each child will get one? which would mean a solution like $6^{13}$.

Then I also thought, "what about the children who don't get books, do I have to account for all the different ways that can occur too?  So that would be something of the sort $\binom{13}{6}\times7!$

I know I am overthinking,  but how far am I going?

Comment: If the question was different types of books it would have said so.  I think it's safe to assume there are six physical books only.  The children who don't get books are precisely the children who are not the children who do get books so if you calculate one, you calculate the other.  What *I'm* unsure of is whether all six books *must* be distributed are whether it's possible that no children get any books, or four children get books and the two extra books are tossed into the fire, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should choose the six children that will receive the books, i.e., $\binom{13}{6}$, and then you should multiple it by the number of permutations of the six different books among the six children, i.e., $6!$, thus $\binom{13}{6}6!$ .

Comment: What if fewer then six children get books.  It never says that all the are handed out.

Comment: Then, I guess, you should sum for all possible cases (where case defined as the number of books you give), i.e., $\sum_{i=0}^{6}\binom{13}{i}\binom{6}{i}i!$, where $i$ denote the number of books you want to distribute.

Comment: Yeah, briefly I thought it'd be ${14 \choose 6}6!$ but of course it isn't.   Never mind, my interpretation is probably incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

number of selecting children is ${13 \choose 6}$ and 6 books can be arranged among themselves is $6!$ ways thus the answer is ${13 \choose 6}.6!$.